# Extracting information by row and col in unix bash

Tags: bash, unix

How can you extract information by row and column in Unix bash?

I found this:

```
awk 'NR==3 { print $4 }'
```

And I used it in with top like this(it extracts the whole column):

```
top | awk 'NR==3 { print $4 }'
```

Comment: `awk` is the correct tool for the job, however, you must modify your use of `top` to output only one iteration and exit See `man 1 top` and the `-n` option. What do you want? CPU0 load? There are better ways to get that than `top`. There are answers on the site for 'bash cpu load' which provide alternatives for the calculation. Here is one using `top`, [How to determine how much CPU load...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6909546/3422102)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am supposed to extract 1 process, its PID and name from /proc dir but I don't know for what file I'm supposed to look there I was trying to do something with top. Do you any idea?

Comment: You may want to use `pidof 'process_name'` to find the PID of the process you need info on. (or `ps axf | grep process_name`) Then you can examine the information in `/proc/the_pid/` to gather a bevy of information on that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try top with `-b -n` options; `-b` for batch mode, `-n` for running number of iteration of `top`. You can also filter "`top`" output like `top -b -n 1 | grep sshd` to see only the data for the "`sshd`" process or `top -b -n 1 | grep "sshd" | head -1 |awk '{print $4}'` to get the 4th column of the `sshd` process data (the `VIRT` value).

Please note that you can easily replace the `grep` and `head` with just awk expressions. For instance, you can issue something like this to print the PID, CPU and MEM values.

```sh
top -b -n 1 | awk '$12 == "sshd" {print $1 "\t" $9 "\t" $10}'
```

Comment: `... | grep  ,,, |head ... |... awk` == `.... | awk '/[s]shd/ && NR==1 {print $4}'` . Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter that's a fair point. I thought, using pipe would be more readable. thanks for your comments.

Comment: yes, not trying to be doctrinaire about it, the trade off is for one-offs, rapid development and readability vs minimum process(es) to accomplish a task. (IMHO ;-) ). (I did upvote your answer). Good luck to all.